# How to avoid complex numbers in numerical integration?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

Consider the following function:

```
functest[kT2_, pT1_, pT2_] = pT1*pT2/Sqrt[
 2 kT2 (pT1^2 + pT2^2) - kT2^2 - (pT1^2 - pT2^2)^2]
```

Its denominator contains zeros, and the function becomes imaginary outside of the domain `ImaginaryRoots`:

```
ImaginaryRoots[pT1_, pT2_] = 
 kT2 /. Solve[functest[kT2, pT1, pT2]^-1 == 0, kT2] // Simplify
```

I would like to evaluate the integral where the function is real, so I include `Boole`:

```
int[kT2_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Boole[ImaginaryRoots[pT1, pT2][[1]] < kT2 < 
     ImaginaryRoots[pT1, pT2][[2]]]*functest[kT2, pT1, pT2], {pT1, 0, 
   1}, {pT2, 0, 1}]
```

However, it does not work properly:

```
int[0.0000001]
```

> 0.78524 -6.54641 I

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: It's probably worth reporting to WRI. It seems a bug, or at least a buglet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat a mystery to me.  The trouble seems connected to symbolic processing and singularity handling, perhaps. I don't have time to investigate thoroughly.

Here's one way to workaround it, by hiding `Boole` and explicitly passing the singularities in the `Exclusions` option:

```
fT[kT2_?NumericQ, pT1_?NumericQ, pT2_?NumericQ] := 
  With[{res = functest[kT2, pT1, pT2]},
   Boole[Im@res == 0] res
   ];

int[kT2_] := NIntegrate[fT[kT2, pT1, pT2], {pT1, 0, 1}, {pT2, 0, 1},
   Exclusions -> Thread[imaginaryRoots[pT1, pT2] == kT2], 
   AccuracyGoal -> 100];

int[0.0000001]

(*  0.78524  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

For this one you can use exact integration.

But for numerical, Mathematica does give warnings? It says

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It says above `Suspect one of the following`. So you could follow these warnings and try to correct them?

But why not try exact integration. There is no complex part

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
functest[kT2_, pT1_, pT2_] = pT1*pT2/Sqrt[2 kT2 (pT1^2 + pT2^2) - kT2^2 - (pT1^2 - pT2^2)^2];
ImaginaryRoots[pT1_, pT2_] = kT2 /. Solve[functest[kT2, pT1, pT2]^-1 == 0, kT2] // Simplify;
integrand[kT2_] := Boole[ImaginaryRoots[pT1, pT2][[1]] < kT2 < 
     ImaginaryRoots[pT1, pT2][[2]]]*functest[kT2, pT1, pT2];

sol=Integrate[integrand[Rationalize@0.0000001], {pT1, 0, 1}, {pT2, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
 N[sol] // Chop
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]